# Python thread I/O Error When Copying

Tags: python, file-io, python-multithreading

Let me thank everyone in advance for the help!  FYI, I'm running Python 2.5 (outdated I know, but I am forced to use this version) in Windows 7-64 bit.

I have several directories that each contain large amounts of data.  I want to reduce the amount of time it takes to copy these large directories from my local HD to a network drive.  To do this, I had the bright idea of using individual threads to call the "move" functionality from the shutil library (forgive me, I know not what I do).  Where I run in to problems is when a thread attempts to move a directory, it tells me "[errno 13] Permission denied".

Here is the general layout of my problem:

```
import shutil, threading
from Queue import Queue
def parentFunc():
    fileQ = Queue() #initialize a work queue
    lstDirsOld = ['C:\\LargeDirA','C:\\LargeDirB','C:\\LargeDirC','C:\\LargeDirD']
    lstDirsNew = ['H:\\LargeDirA','H:\\LargeDirB','H:\\LargeDirC','H:\\LargeDirD']

    for i in range(len(lstDirsOld)): #build the work queue
        fileQ.put(lstDirsOld[i],lstDirsNew[i])

    for i in range(len(lstDirsOld)): #attempt to copy files
        worker = Thread(target=childFunc,args=(fileQ,))
        worker.isDaemon = True
        worker.start()  #returns Errno 13


def childFunc(fileQ):
    while True:
        try:
            src,dst = fileQ.get()
            shutil.move(src,dst) #apparently this doesn't work in a thread
            fileQ.task_done()
        except Exception, e:
            print(str(e))
```

I tried moving the move command to the parentFunc and it worked fine.  I'm hesitant to call this a solution, though, since it will take a great amount of time to copy the directories.

It feels like the answer is staring me in the face.  Since I'm an engineer and not a programmer I am having trouble seeing my mistake, so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would be surprised if that made things any faster. All the limiting factors (disk I/O, network I/O) are unaffected by thereading; however, you force a much higher ratio of seeks to bytes written/read on the disk (because you're trying to read/write from several different places at once, forcing the OS to alternate between them), which should make things worse. The only way this could help is if network latency is the issue, which is unlikely in a move operation.

Comment: why do you set isDaemon to True?

Comment: This is part of a larger program.  If the main program crashes there would be no need to continue copying.  You would have to fix other issues before the information would be useful to copy.